# XCode 8: Unable to set Size

Tags: ios, xcode8

Since the update to Xcode 8 I'm unable to set the size of the initial ViewController (which is then inherited to all other Views). In the past I could set something like iPhone 5, etc. Now I can only set Inferred, etc...

Where can I set the size?

[image]

Comment: open your storyboard file, there exist an option for view as for devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 8. In the bottom left you can see

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check below screen shot

1 .Set your viewcontroller's size to freedom

[image]

2 .Then set size as per your need.

[image]